# OnePlus one constantly freezes and ends up crashing

Tags: crashes, oneplus-one, system-freeze

Ever since this morning my OnePlus one suddenly freezes constantly, refuses to open certain apps (for instance, WhatsApp works but Facebook doesn't), crash whatever apps do work and if left alone it will just crash the system ui and leave me with a black screen, forcing me to reboot every five minutes or so.

I think it has to do with some buggy update that my phone did overnight, but I can't find the cause of the problem. These are the specs of my phone:

- **OS + version**: OxygenOS 2.1.4
- **Android version**: 5.1.1

If someone could tell me if this is a known bug or if there's a workaround, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try booting in recovery and clear the cache memory. If it doesn't help, reset the phone to factory.

Comment: @esQmo tried doing that, doesn't work :/

Comment: So you'll need to flash the whole phone. Download the stock firmware and flah your phone.

Comment: @esQmo well shit, here goes that hell again